# Rails - Using jquery to get page view from controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a select_tag to find a customer id and then send it to the controller to render the show page.

```
<%= select_tag( "cust_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@customers.by_last_name, :id, :last_name, (@customers_id.nil?) ? nil : @customers_id), {:class => 'custTag'}) %>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready
$(document).on('change', '.custTag', function(){

    var custId = $(this).val();
    alert (custId);
    $.get('/customers/custId');

});
```

I am having two problems:

1. While the alert shows the customer id(custId) associated with the record, the server is responding with the message - `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=custId)`.
2. If I put the id directly in the code `($.get('/customers/6559');)` The controller responds with `Processing by CustomersController#show as '*/*'`.

And nothing is rendered - the server does receive the entered id and appears to be processing the request as if I have entered the request directly in the browser address bar

I apologize in advance for my ignorance - I am very new to this process.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems merit two answers.

1) Rails routing has URL params, meaning `/customers/:id` where `:id` is the param. You're select and JQuery code is fine, as you've confirmed yourself, but you need to add the `custId` to the string in your `$.get` to send the actual id.

Currently you're request is `/customers/custId` so it's trying to find id = `custId`...

```
$.get('/customers/' + custId);
```

2) AJAX need to be handled otherwise nothing happens. You're request is sent, response sent back to your JS, then nothing because nothing is defined.

What do you want to have happen exactly? Did you try doing this via HTML instead of JS?

I'd say what you want is to have the page re-rendered to `show`, so...

```
$.get('/customers/' + custId).done(function(data){
  $(document).html(data) // something like this to replace the content
})
```

The rule of thumb with these things is, do it with HTML FIRST! Then use AJAX to if you feel it's appropriate.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you! The first answer was just what I needed to send the custId to the get request - I appreciate you helping me with this syntax. Now I need to get the customer show page rendered. Right now I get the following :Processing by CustomersController#show as `*/*` Instead of Processing by CustomersController#show as HTML which is what I get when I enter the id on the browser address bar.. How do I get the HTML rendered?

Comment: That's part 2). I was avoid the AJAX approach if you do not really understand what you are doing :/ But essentially when asking for HTML the browser just renders that, but using AJAX, you must manipulate the DOM to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Again I apologize for my ignorance. I also appreciate you patience in helping me.I feel that I am almost to the goal and I wanted to ask, if you would be so kine, if you g=could give me a tip on either how to get the HTML page for the controller show action for the customer or how to get the jquery to respond to the request with an HTML rendering, not a `*.* rendering

Comment: Hey man we all start somewhere right? ;) Don't worry about it.

Comment: Yes, I know I am on the steep end of the learning curve - I was a COBOL programmer many years ago and spend the last 20 or so using Access for my database work. I want to learn how to have the database on the web now, though

Comment: Luckily, Rails makes this easy. Web framework like Rails have ORM (Object Relational Mapping) and ActiveRecord (framework within framework) is database agnostic, meaning it has a domain specific language that applies to whatever DB you're using :)